# Why does calling Breeze metadata() return an error with .net core 3.0.100

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, breeze

Until now I've been using Breeze on .net framework. Works great. For a new project I want to switch to .net core 3.0.100 to write the backend software, aka web api.

So this is my first time setup of a .net core web api application with breeze and EF.
Setup per https://github.com/Breeze/northwind-core-ng-demo

1. .netcore 3.0.100
2. Breeze .netcore
3. Breeze persistence EFCore
4. Entity framework SQLServer

**Calling Metadata() on persistencemanager throws an error:**

```
Message [string]:"Method not found: 'System.Type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty.get_ClrType()'."
```

Detailed error:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.MissingMethodException
An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Method not found: 'System.Type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty.get_ClrType()'.'
   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.MetadataBuilder.CreateDataProperty(IProperty p)
   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.MetadataBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateMetaType>b__0(IProperty p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToList()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.MetadataBuilder.CreateMetaType(IEntityType et, Dictionary`2 dbSetMap)
   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.MetadataBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GetMetadataFromContext>b__1(IEntityType et)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToList()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.MetadataBuilder.GetMetadataFromContext(DbContext dbContext)
   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.MetadataBuilder.BuildFrom(DbContext dbContext)
   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.EFPersistenceManager`1.BuildJsonMetadata()
   at Breeze.Persistence.PersistenceManager.Metadata()
   at JobtrackerBOBreezeController.metaData() in /Users/roydecaestecker/Documents/angular-cli-apps/sulo-solution/Sulo.Jobtracker.BO.Api/Controllers/JobtrackerBOBreezeController.cs:line 21
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Klant model

```
[Table("klant", Schema="Sulo")]
    public class Klant
    {
        public Klant(){}

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string naam { get; set; }
    }
```

DBContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Sulo.Jobtracker.Model
{
    public class SuloJobtrackerContext : DbContext
    {
        public SuloJobtrackerContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }


        public DbSet<Klant> klanten { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Klant>();
        }
    }
}
```

Project file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>...</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Sulo.Jobtracker.Model\Sulo.Jobtracker.Model.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Breeze.AspNetCore.NetCore" Version="1.0.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Breeze.Persistence.EFCore" Version="1.0.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Breeze controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using Breeze.Persistence;
using Breeze.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

[Breeze.AspNetCore.BreezeQueryFilter]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]/[action]")]
public class JobtrackerBOBreezeController {
    private SuloJobtrackerPersistenceManager persistenceManager;


    public JobtrackerBOBreezeController(SuloJobtrackerContext dbcontext){
        persistenceManager = new SuloJobtrackerPersistenceManager(dbcontext);
    }

    [HttpGet, HttpOptions]
    public string  metaData() {
        return persistenceManager.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet, HttpOptions]
    [Authorize]
    public IQueryable<Klant> klanten() {
        return persistenceManager.Context.klanten;
    }


}
```

**calling klanten() method works just fine**

Comment: https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/issues/87

Comment: ok, tx. I'll stick to .net framework. Any idea when Breeze will be available for .net core 3... ?

Answer (score 1):

Breeze support of .NET Core 3 [has been released](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.Persistence.EFCore/).

And the https://github.com/Breeze/northwind-demo is updated.